# Prepare and backup Wii U for sale

Tags: wii-u

I'm letting my Wii U go. Since I'm not switching to another unit (at least right now), what do I need to do and backup with Nintendo's weird protection policies to ensure that I can use my game saves and the games I purchased in the future on another unit? Or is everything lost because I'm not doing a direct account transfer (with both old and new Wii Us in my possession at once)? Is there anything else I should do before parting with the console?

Answer (score 1):

To reset all settings and content back to factory settings do the following;

- Start up your Wii U
- Go to Settings
- Go to Delete All Contents and Settings
- Press A to select
- Enter Parent Control PIN as required
- Go to Next
- Go to Delete Everything

Comment: What about the backup?

Comment: @Sean: The software is tied to the hardware. You lose the hardware, you lose the software. It's stupid but that's just how it is.

Comment: You should be able to initiate a transfer, but since you don't have a replacement system, there is nothing to transfer to.  Try to contact Nintendo whether you can keep those software in "limbo" until a future date, like some sort of code to "release" the software back on to a system.

Comment: @Sean Still having problems with your Wii U? Let's talk about it - [click here.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32368/everything-nintendo)